# Modifying body of method with Roslyn

Tags: c#, syntax, roslyn

Is there some way to add a specific statement at the end of a method in a .cs file with Roslyn?

```
var code = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\PersonalUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SampleToAnalyze\SampleToAnalyze\ClassChild.cs").ReadToEnd();
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
var root = tree.GetRoot();
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation", new[] { tree },
          new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) });
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

MethodDeclarationSyntax myMethod= tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes()
                                      .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().Last();

StatementSyntax myStatement= SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement(@"Console.WriteLine();");
```

I want to insert "myStatement" at the end of method "myMethod".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [the `AddBodyStatements` method](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/2.3.0/netstandard1.3/doc/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.MethodDeclarationSyntax/AddBodyStatements(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.StatementSyntax$)) to create a new `MethodDeclarationSyntax` with the statement added and then use [`ReplaceNode`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common/2.3.0/netstandard1.3/doc/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNodeExtensions/ReplaceNode''1(''0,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode)) to update the `SyntaxTree`:

```
var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(myMethod, myMethod.AddBodyStatements(myStatement));
```

This will create code that's valid C#, but looks wrong, because it's badly indented. Probably the simplest way to fix that is to also call `Formatter.Format`:

```
newRoot = Formatter.Format(newRoot, new AdhocWorkspace());
```

Comment: it doesn't work. When I open the file there is not the line that I added

Comment: Ok it works. I added this line  File.WriteAllText(file, newRoot.ToFullString()); to your code. Thank you so much!